# Matlab scatter diagram

Tags: software-recommendation, statistics

I have two columns of data, x and y, how can I make a ‘thermodynamic diagram’ with matlab? The z axis is the density value of dots, like below figure.
[image]
[image]

The x-axis is angle, y-axis is distance.[image]
I want to construct a heatmap like this figure:[image]

Comment: Hi, how is this related to bioinformatics? What have you tried? I don't know if you want your data like in the second plot or like in the first one. Could you provide a some data to test solutions?

Answer (score 4):

A reverse image search on google leads to the [exact code](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BicubicInterpolationExample.png) used to produce the second image:

```
[Xcoarse, Ycoarse] = meshgrid([0 1 2 3], [0 1 2 3]);
[Xfine, Yfine] = meshgrid(linspace(0,3,3000), linspace(0,3,3000));
DataCoarse = [ 1 2 4 1; ...
           6 3 5 2; ...
           4 2 1 5; ...
           5 4 2 3];
DataBicubicFine  = interp2(Xcoarse, Ycoarse, DataCoarse, Xfine, Yfine, 'bicubic');
figure
surf(Xfine, Yfine, DataBicubicFine); shading flat; colormap(jet); view(0, 90)
 hold on; plot3(Xcoarse, Ycoarse, 10*ones(size(Xcoarse)), 'k.', 'MarkerSize', 20)
colorbar
print -dpng -r300 BicubicInterpolationExample.png
```